# slideToggle jquery - close all

Tags: jquery

I'm using slidetoggle (http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to expand/contract divs within a list - i'd like to close all before opening a further link so only one div is open at any time - is this possible?

I'm currently just toggling the individual divs on click using -

```
         $(this).find(".listContentN").slideToggle(500);
```

Comment: `$(this).find(".listContentN").slideToggle(500).end().siblings().find(".listContentN").slideUp(500);`

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, but why you not define it on parent selector:

```
$(".ELEMENT .listContentN").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".listContentN").slideToggle(500);
   $(this).slideToggle(500);
});
```